# Repeating nodes are skipped in DataTable when converting xml to DataSet c#

Tags: c#, xml

```
var reader = new StringReader(xDoc.OuterXml);
ds.ReadXml(reader);
```

below is the xml:

```
<SubscriberEligibilityOrBenefitInformationLoop>
    <SubscriberEligibilityOrBenefitInformation>
        <EligibilityBenefitInf>Active Coverage</EligibilityBenefitInf>
        <ServiceTypeCode>Medical Care</ServiceTypeCode>
        <ServiceTypeCode>Chiropractic</ServiceTypeCode>
        <ServiceTypeCode>Hospital</ServiceTypeCode>
        <InPlanNetworkIndicator>Not Applicable</InPlanNetworkIndicator>
    </SubscriberEligibilityOrBenefitInformation>
</SubscriberEligibilityOrBenefitInformationLoop>
```

when I convert this xml to DataSet, the repeating nodes (for example
< ServiceTypeCode >) are skipped in DataTable's column.
Why this skipping the repeating nodes?

Comment: Add please, the code of converting

Comment: I have already mentioned it above.

Comment: Here it is:
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

                    xDoc.LoadXml(anyString);
                    var reader = new StringReader(xDoc.OuterXml);
                    ds.ReadXml(reader);

Comment: how do you want `DataSet` to interpret the same columns?

Comment: I want to represent data in the same column, with comma separation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your XML DataSet creates 2 tables, one with root object and the other with repeated elements, to make it fit to each other it generates also a `Key` column to a root table, and `FK` column in child table:

[image]

and

[image]

So you can use that data to build a new column (Try to dig into [Expression column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Codes");
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    row["Codes"] = string.Join(",", ds.Tables[1]
                    .Select($"SubscriberEligibilityOrBenefitInformation_ID = {row["SubscriberEligibilityOrBenefitInformation_ID"]}")
                    .Select(r=>r["ServiceTypeCode_Text"]));
}
```

Comment: Yes.. thats the way! Actually i wasnt familiar to the thing that repeated nodes are placed in separate DataTable. 
Now i can manipulate it as my desire. Thanks @ASpirin for your help!!

Comment: Already done it, but I'm new here so stackOverflow is not considering my mark :|